# Remove blank line after a match

Tags: bash, sed

Imagine the following example input file:

```
(1)    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      vero eos et accusam et justo duo

(2)    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

   vero eos et accusam et justo duo

(3)    Lorem ipsum -- dolor sit amet
      vero eos et accusam et justo duo

(4)    Lorem -- ipsum dolor sit amet

   vero eos et accusam et justo duo
```

I am interested in finding all lines ending with the keyword `amet` and not containing the keyword `--` in a script. If such a line is found the successor line should be removed if it is blank. So only the second (2) example has to be changed:

```
(1)    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      vero eos et accusam et justo duo

(2)    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
   vero eos et accusam et justo duo

(3)    Lorem ipsum -- dolor sit amet
      vero eos et accusam et justo duo

(4)    Lorem -- ipsum dolor sit amet

   vero eos et accusam et justo duo
```

Comment: Please don't forget to post your attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sed command would work:

```
sed '/--/b;/amet$/{N;s/\n$//;}'
```

It does the following:

```
/--/b        # If line matches "--", skip all commands
/amet$/ {    # If the line ends in "amet"
    N        # Read next line into pattern space
    s/\n$//  # Delete the second line if it is blank
}
```

This would fail for a few edge cases: does a line ending in `blamet` qualify? Does `--` have to be separated by blanks? Could there ever be input like this:

```
ends in amet
also ends in amet

next line
```

as the solution presented would not remove the blank line here. For the presented input, though, it would work.

Answer (score 2):

Let's create it bit by bit:

- Process only lines that end with `amet` (using the GNU `\b` to match a word boundary):

  ```
  /\bamet$/
  ```
- If it doesn't contain `--`

  ```
  /--/!
  ```
- Then print the line

  ```
  n
  ```
- And if the next line is empty, delete it

  ```
  /^$/d
  ```

That gives this simple program:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

# Process only lines that end with `amet`:
/\bamet$/{
# If it doesn't contain `--`
/--/!{
# Then print the line
n
# And if the next line is empty, delete it
/^$/d
}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `n` skip all other commands? This doesn't delete the empty line for me.

Comment: Ah, never, mind, the `\b` threw my sed off (as it's a GNU extension).

Comment: Oh, sorry - I thought that was standard sed.  I do normally mention any GNUisms when I'm aware of them...